# Change default date format to %Y%m%d%H%M%S

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 3 and I want to change the default date format of created_at and updated_at date when I save them into the db.

Default date format is `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, but
I would like it to be `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

Where should I change the format? I'm trying to create a time_formats.rb in the initializer folder.

Here is content:

```
class TimeFormats
  Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db] = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
  Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
end
```

This does not work. Is there someone who can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The time and date formats that you define in the initializers apply only when converting them to strings in Ruby. The formats you've defined would be used like `Time.now.to_s(:default)`.

I don't recommend (nor am I aware of a way how) to change how dates are stored in the database. You should let the database store them as it does by default, then change how they are formatted in the views using `.to_s(:format)` as defined in the initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the database stores the timestamps as a specific timedate datatype rather than a formatted string. If you just want default timestamp printing style to be different, you might try overriding the created_at and updated_at methods:

```
  def updated_at
    super.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") 
  end
```